# Please help me identify this molding

Tags: trim, renovation

Please help me figure out what kind of trim this is so I can order/buy some, or match it as close as possible.

Seems like real wood core w/plasticky wood-grain veneer. People comment it looks kinda 80s, though house was built early 2000s. The casings and moldings are all made of same stuff.

Doing renovations in a vacation home, had to demo some floor/walls, need to match same molding (original ones in house) outside of these areas.

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are the dimensions

Comment: It looks like stained pine from a big box store.

Comment: Google search "pine baseboards"

Comment: Edited to embed the images. Also removed requests on where to find it as that might get this closed as a shopping question, which is off topic. Also, identifying the species is difficult enough from pictures that it's actually off-topic at the [woodworking.se] site, so bare in mind that any species info you get here will be guesses at best.

Comment: @Ruskes Sizing:

Comment: @Ruskes Sizing:
It's just shy of 2 1/4 inches high (if used as floor molding), just shy of 1/2 inch wide on bottom, and just shy of 1/4 inch wide on top. 

Sorry if anything in response is off, im new to this site

Answer (score 9):

That looks like bevel casing, possibly oak.

Take your sample to local lumberyards (not big box stores) and see what they have.

If you can’t find an exact match, replace everything in the immediate vicinity. Most people won’t notice the difference.

Comment: If your local lumber yard doesn't stock it or can't make it, they'll point you to a local cabinet maker who can.

Comment: To affirm the last sentence: I had a similar issue and ended up replacing the casing around one side of a door. Similar profile, but the size was 1/4" wider. No one notices the difference.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense - do they normally sell these casings with the plasticky veneer outside this one has?

Comment: ‘Foil’ wrapped ones do exist, though this doesn’t look like that to me. Either way, you’ll be able to find something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this image, I'd say that this is "paint grade pine trim", or something similar.

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

I initially thought that the dark bit on the right was some stain that had gotten on the back, perhaps from being dipped. It is, in fact, some type of finger joint.

This trim was made from smaller pieces (left overs, bits after the knots were cut out, whatever), joined together to make longer pieces. This was intended to be painted, not stained, as the paint would hide the grain, color differences, and joint itself between the different pieces of wood.

You could take this piece to a lumber yard (as suggested by [Aloysius](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/252977/34147)) and they'll be able to help you match real wood to the fake-wood grain pattern. Then you can stain the real wood to match. Check out the [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) sister site for tips on how to match stain colors.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense... it has a plasticky veneer on the outside, but will try Dyke's Lumber, apparently they have "everything" ... in NJ, USA